# How to setup my HTML table layout

Tags: html, css

I need help with a HTML layout.

I need to show 3 columns for each table row

Column#1 just has some text in it

Column#2 Has a inner table, with either 1 or 2 rows depending on the contents of Column#3

Column#3 Has x number of rows, each word in the row has a name of a food item.  Healthy items are listed first, and (if any) unhealthy items are listed.
  If there are ONLY healthy items, column#2 will have 1 row with the word "HEALTHY" in it.
  Otherwise, it will display HEALTHY, and the 2nd row will have UNHEALTHY (and it has to lineup with column#3)

So it would look like:

```
Column#2        Column#3
HEATHLY         Apple
                Pear
```

Or it may look like:

```
Column#2        Column#3
HEATHLY         Apple
                Pear
UNHEALTHY       Coffee crispt
                Chocolate milk
```

And each row in column #2 and column#3 should have grids (border top/bottom) for each row.

How can I do this?

Note:  The row border in column#2 should lineup with the row borders in column#3.

I hope I explained this clear enough.

Comment: It'd be faster if you posted what you already have, so one could just edit it.

Comment: Are you dynamically generating this content? Or it is a static page?

Comment: mine is server side generated, and I can't post the output for privacy reasons.  Plus my solution doesn't seem ideal, don't want to sway a better solution.

Comment: What language are you using? Are these values in some sort of array?

Comment: @FlyingMolga the content is not relevant, its the html/css layout/structure that I am asking about.

Comment: If you're dynamically generating data, how the content is stored could affect how you'll create the table. Unless your data will never change and you only need one static table structure.

Comment: your example table layout doesn't have a first column?

Comment: the first column is a single row with text.

Comment: This particular data looks like it's more suited to nested lists than a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking for in particular so here goes:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Col 1</td>
        <td>Col 2</td>
        <td>Col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">Col 1 text goes here</td>
        <td rowspan="2">HEALTHY</td>
        <td>Apple</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pear</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">UNHEALTHY</td>
        <td>Toffee crisp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Chocolate milk</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And some pseudo code to generate it:

```
foreach c2 in col-2-items
{
    foreach c3 in c2.col-3-items
    {
        <tr>
            if c3 is first in c2.col-3-items
            {
                if c2 is first in col-2-items
                {
                    <td rowspan="all-items.count">Col 1 text goes here</td>
                }
                <td rowspan="c2.col-3-items.count">c2.text</td>
            }
            <td>c3.text</td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Apply top and bottom borders with css. Note also the cellspacing="0" on the table.

```
<style>
table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td
{
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}
</style>
```

Comment: one of the main things is the row borders

Comment: @user1361315 If you don't nest your tables, the borders will solve themselves.

Comment: @MrLister doesn't look that way to me: http://jsfiddle.net/UhKX4/  Or is it just missing the row borders?

Comment: @user1361315 Yes. See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UhKX4/2/) that incorporates flem's CSS.